# How to do a match and replace on javascript object

Tags: javascript, regex, object

Does anyone know how to do a match and replace on a javascript object value? For example:

```
var obj = {
  name: '/asdf/sdfdsf/:_id',
  type: 'dfdfdf'
}

obj.name = obj.replace(':_id', 'replacement');
```

I want the resulting object to be:

```
obj = {
  name: '/asdf/sdfdsf/replacement',
  type: 'dfdfdf'
}
```

However, this gives me the error `obj.replace is not a function`. Can someone help?

Comment: Stringify the object and do a replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is applied on a string, not an object, here is working code

```js
var obj = {
  name: '/asdf/sdfdsf/:_id',
  type: 'dfdfdf'
}

// change is here
obj.name = obj.name.replace(':_id', 'replacement');

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` function on an object. Use `Object.keys()` instead to catch every property and replace it's key.

```js
var obj = {
  name: '/asdf/sdfdsf/:_id',
  type: 'dfdfdf'
}

//if you want to change :_id in few keys
var res = Object.keys(obj).map(v => obj[v].replace(':_id', 'replacement'));
console.log(res);

//if you want to change it only in one, specified property - use direct reference
var singleObj = obj.name.replace(':_id', 'replacement');
console.log(singleObj);
```

Comment: This is a more general solution, however replace would throw if the value is another object, so you might wanna check that and either return or do it recursively (deep)

Comment: @leo Your solution (solution on his particular problem) seems too trivial to even bother making an own answer... I just wanted to add something extra.

Comment: I agree, my solution is simple, but complete, because it only covers a very specific use case. The one proposed tried to be more general, but working only halfway and could break. Not criticising, just suggesting to make it complete so the OP can accept your answer as it would be then better :- )

Comment: @leo Agreed, but honestly I'd prefer to mark it as a dupe then posting this 'complete' answer... xd

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the single string in the object:

```
obj.name = obj.name.replace (':_id', 'replacement')
```

If you want to replace all strings in the object:

```
for (x in obj) {
    if (typeof (obj[x]) == 'string')
        obj [x] = obj [x].replace (':_id', 'whee!')
}
```

If you're certain the object only contains strings, you can remove the 'if' from the loop.  This is non-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a replace on object you can use one function like that.

```js
var obj = {
  name: '/asdf/sdfdsf/replacement/_id',
  type: 'dfdfdf'
};
var replaceInObject=function(object,word,value){
  var string=JSON.stringify(object);
  string=string.replace(word,value);
  object=JSON.parse(string);
  return object;
}

console.log(replaceInObject(obj,'_id','testID'));
```